# Not able to move web parts from the edit page view

Tags: 2007, web-part

I just completed work on a Publishing Site collection for MOSS 2007 that is using a custom master page that I developed.  The stylesheet that I am using holds all the overrides of the core.css.  This includes web part titles etc.   All the page layouts that I use are reflective of all the styles and use the Master Page as intended.   When I go to edit the page and want to move web parts to different zones I no longer have that ability.  The browser kicks back and error indicating an object required message everytime I select the web part i am wishing to move.

I am thinking that one of my styles might be causing this issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

So I dug a bit deeper and the issue was in my CSS.   I had a style that controlled the full height of the page.  There as a setting for position:relative.   I commented this out and we now have success.
[Here](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/tmt/archive/2007/11/01/CSS-causes-JavaScript-error-while-moving-Web-Parts-in-edit-mode.aspx) is an article that can be used as a reference

Comment: Excellent.  So it was a js issue, just caused by CSS!  Can you mark this as the answer.  I can see that link being really useful to some folks.

Comment: I had a similar issue with css making the dropdown boxes on the create view page act funny. They would draw and then disappear and would flash when you scrolled the page. Once I replaced the css they were normal again.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like an issue with JavaScript.

The 'object required' message would indicate a js issue to me.  Are using any custom js scripts from your master page?

Comment: this is the only script I have in Master 
<script type="text/javascript">  
 if(document.title!='') {
document.title = 'Clinical Trials Learning Center - ' + document.title;
 } else {
document.title = 'Clinical Trials Learning Center';
 }
</script>
Commented it out and still no go on moving web parts

Comment: Your not linking to any additional js libraries.  No JQuery.  No Lightbox type of stuff?

Comment: i am going to compare the default to my new master to see what I can find out.  Also, one other thing to note is when I click on one webpart in lets say the right zone, all the titles get highlighted.  This might tell us something more.